# Is it okay if a student wears a mask to class to conceal scars?

Tags: health, outward-appearance

Like a halloween mask to conceal injuries of a burn?

Comment: What sort of halloween mask did you have in mind?

Comment: I would make sure to notify the instructor of the class in advance if you're planning on doing this.

Comment: Have you asked your instructor(s)?

Answer (score 15):

Of course. If there's a medical reason for it and the student can produce an appropriate doctor's certificate or what not. You would need to check the regulations.

It probably depends on what sort of mask it is. If the mask is distracting for other students  or plain silly, then I can imagine that it is reasonable to object to it. So, 'halloween mask' may not be the best description of an appropriate mask.

Answer (score 12):

You will definitely need to check regulations regarding the wearing of costumes that conceal one's appearance. For example, in France it's [forbidden by law to conceal one's face in public space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_ban_on_face_covering), including in universities (and it's made explicit in universities' by-laws). While there's normally allowances made for legitimate medical reasons, there will definitely be limits. "Halloween-style" costumes and masks will probably be disallowed.

One additional comment not mentioned in Dave's answer is that in cases of laboratories and other "practical" exercises, such costumes may be disallowed for legal and protective reasons. You will need to talk with the appropriate staff about any accommodations that can be made.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: Yes, you can do that.

Comment: There are mask laws in the United States, too.  In my state, Georgia, it was intended as a weapon against masked thuggery and might not be enforced in the case described.  However, "might not be enforced" is pretty thin ice upon which to walk.

Answer (score 11):

In general, I second Dave's answer. There is one point, however. During exams students have to identify themselves, and this is commonly done by showing some identification document (e.g., student id) to the person in charge. Wearing a mask would likely be interpreted as a failure to identify yourself, unless identification is possible in some other way. As a rule, failing to identify yourself at our university means that the lecturer is not allowed to grade the exam. However, if wearing a mask is required due to a medical condition, the student can notify the examination board *before the exam* that can decide to deviate from the identification rule and oblige the lecturer to grade the exam.